# Securest way to transaction a value of a variable to webbrowser?

Tags: c#, security

example code

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
string securedKey = "1ed9f7e4";
```

and I want to transfer the variable "securedKey" to the WebBrowser object on the same form. I can do it per POST or GET but its not secure.

I can encrypt the variable and then send to the Web but its easy to debug the application and see how I encrypt and where to send it.

What is the securest way to do something like that?

Comment: Is it enought to use only SSL?

Comment: HTTP over SSL *is* HTTPS.

Comment: I know and I have asked, using SSL (HTTPS) only enought?

Comment: @daniel How web security should be done in general is a **HUGE** question and depends on context. As for SSL, prefer TLS over it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thats true but the question is not about the web security. There must be a logic to transfer datas from software to web in secure way and that is all I want to know. (Decompiling and manupulating the application is not included).

Comment: That's a _huge_ question, there are courses in university about it. If you could specify your scenario, what sort of security you'd like to achieve and which part you'd like to make secure (Sending data from your app to the web?) That'd be awesome. Also, if you could specify what you mean by secure, safe from MITM attacks? ETC.. Also, this is a (broad) great resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS instead of HTTP. There are other ways, but since you specifically asked for most secure, that's your only option.